# Python handle expired refresh token of Oauth2

Tags: python, http, oauth-2.0

I am integrating one API. The problem is the refresh token which is used to get access token is only valid for 14 days. After that, people need to regenerate a new refresh token. Now I can obtain the refresh token successfully by opening a web browser, but this is not convenient and the script cannot be scheduled to run automatically. Does anyone know how to get a new refresh token through HTTP request? Now I am able to get refresh token by opening web browser. However, when call the server with following code, it gives a HTML page as response. See following code:

```
aurl = 'https://webapi.timedoctor.com/oauth/v2/auth?client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}'

resp = requests.get(aurl)

print resp.text
```

As a response:

[image]